# Intermittent SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: ssl, binding, transport

We are seeing SecurityNegotiationException when making calls from our Windows service to an api. The issue has been off-and-on. Sometimes it affects all communication attempts and sometimes we only see it for some or none of hundreds of queries against the API in a day.

Interestingly, we can make the same calls using SoapUI from our server and they work fine. We also do not see any evidence of time drift on the machine.

Stack trace and service confiq is included below. Any ideas on what would be causing this?

.NET Windows Service Binding Configuration

```
<binding name="Sevier_Binding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Stack Trace

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
>   'EndpointRemoved'. Void
>   HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)  Server stack trace:
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: Nothing yet.. still looking

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3889
Are you getting the exception on the hour every hour?